# Struts2 : Using HashMap for grid entry

Tags: jsp, struts2, hashmap

I am trying to use a HashMap to create a grid in JSP using Struts2. I am able to load the page with the values I populate in the HashMap, but when I submit it, the HashMap doesn't get back to the action method (I get a NullPointerException trying to access the HashMap). Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Is what I am doing in the JSP correct?

My Action Method (Load and Submit) :-

```
        public class HashMapGridAction extends ActionSupport{

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HashMapGridAction.class);

        private HashMap<String, TestObject> hashMap;

        public String load() {

            this.hashMap = new HashMap<String, TestObject>();

            TestObject testObject1 = new TestObject();
            testObject1.setCode("A");
            testObject1.setDescription("Alphabet A");
            this.hashMap.put("A", testObject1);

            TestObject testObject2 = new TestObject();
            testObject2.setCode("B");
            testObject2.setDescription("Alphabet B");
            this.hashMap.put("B", testObject2);

            TestObject testObject3 = new TestObject();
            testObject3.setCode("C");
            testObject3.setDescription("Alphabet C");
            this.hashMap.put("C", testObject3);

            return SUCCESS;
        }

        public String submit() {

            //This is where I get the NullPointerException          
            Iterator<String> iter = this.hashMap.keySet().iterator();

            while (iter.hasNext()){
                String key = iter.next();
                logger.debug("Key : " + key);
                logger.debug("Code: " + this.hashMap.get(key).getCode());
                logger.debug("Description: " + this.hashMap.get(key).getDescription());
            }

            return SUCCESS;
        }

        public HashMap<String, TestObject> getHashMap() {
            return hashMap;
        }

        public void setHashMap(HashMap<String, TestObject> hashMap) {
            this.hashMap = hashMap;
        }

    }
```

The value object on the HashMap (TestObject) :-

```
public class TestObject {

    private String code;
    private String description;
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }


}
```

JSP :-

```
<s:form action="hashMapGridSubmit">
    <table>

        <s:iterator value="hashMap" var="testObject">

            <tr>
                <s:hidden name="hashMap[%{key}].code" value="%{value.code}"></s:hidden>
                <td><s:property value="%{value.code}" /></td>
                <td><s:textfield theme="simple"
                        name="hashMap[%{key}].description" value="%{value.description}" /></td>
            </tr>

        </s:iterator>

    </table>

    <s:submit theme="simple" value="Submit" />

</s:form>
```

Struts.xml :-

```
<action name="hashMapGridLoad" class="com.dowill.struts2.hashmap.HashMapGridAction" method="load">
    <result name="success">/hashmap/hashmapgrid.jsp</result>
</action>
<action name="hashMapGridSubmit" class="com.dowill.struts2.hashmap.HashMapGridAction" method="submit">
    <result name="success">/hashmap/hashmapgrid.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Thank you !!

Comment: You need to use a type conversion for your indexed properties because you are populating a collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `'`:

```
 <s:hidden name = "hashMap['%{key}'].code" 
          value = "%{value.code}" />

 <s:textfield name = "hashMap['%{key}'].description" 
             value = "%{value.description}" />
```

Also declare the HashMap as a Map:

```
private Map<String, TestObject> hashMap;
```

Comment: Savior ! Thank you for catching both of those !! So, Struts doesn't work with HashMap?